# Unable to test that an Event has properties with Laravel 5 and PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5, mockery

I am attempting to test that my events get the correct properties when they are fired. I am able to determine that an event was fired, but not that the right properties were sent.

**PHP**

```
<?php

use App\Events\ManifestRecordCreated;
use App\ManifestFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ManifestTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * This is the test I'd like to perfom.
     */
    public function testOhLookMyEventGetsTheRightProperties()
    {
      Event::shouldReceive('fire')->once()->withArgs(array('App\\Events\\ManifestRecordCreated', array (
         'poseId' => 2,
         'stateId' => 1,
         'manifestId' => 1,
         )
      ));
      Event::fire(new ManifestRecordCreated(2, 1, 1));
    }
    /**
     * Test that the event is fired.
     */
    public function testOnlyOneThatWorks()
    {
       Event::shouldReceive('fire')->once()->with(Mockery::any());
       Event::fire(new ManifestRecordCreated(2, 1, 1));
    }

    /**
     * I'd like to test if the evnt is getting the right arguments.
     */
    public function testGraspingAtStraws()
    {
      $args = array ('App\Events\ManifestRecordCreated' => array (
        'class' => 'App\Events\ManifestRecordCreated',
        'properties' => array (
         'poseId' => 2,
         'stateId' => 1,
         'manifestId' => 1,
         ),
        'getters' => array (),
        ),
      );
      Event::shouldReceive('fire')->once()->withArgs($args);
      Event::fire(new ManifestRecordCreated(2, 1, 1));
    }
    /**
     * I don't think I need this, but I did read it somewhere in my search.
     */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        \Mockery::close();
    }
}
```

**PHPUnit** Test results

```
1) ManifestTest::testOhLookMyEventGetsTheRightProperties
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_0_Illuminate_Events_Dispatcher::fire(object(App\Events\ManifestRecordCreated)). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method

Objects: ( array (
  'App\\Events\\ManifestRecordCreated' => 
  array (
    'class' => 'App\\Events\\ManifestRecordCreated',
    'properties' => 
    array (
      'poseId' => 2,
      'stateId' => 1,
      'manifestId' => 1,
    ),
    'getters' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
))

2) ManifestTest::testGraspingAtStraws
ErrorException: Undefined offset: 0
```

The [Laravel 5 docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing) aren't super helpful.

[This approach](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/mocking-a-laravel-facade) ignores all but the event.

Answer (score 0):

The `ErrorException: Undefined offset: 0` issue is that the array is passed with named keys, rather than as a 0 to X list of the parameters you expect to be passed. (It's taking `'App\\Events\\ManifestRecordCreated'` as the key name)

Normally you'd just pass in a list, but with object parameters the matching can fail because it's not the same instance, so you can use the hamcrest equalTo method to compare the object value, rather than instance

Something like

```
public function testObjectValuesEqual()
{
  Event::shouldReceive('fire')->once()->withArgs([Matchers::equalTo(new ManifestRecordCreated(2, 1, 1))]);
  Event::fire(new ManifestRecordCreated(2, 1, 1));
}
```